# c++ include redeclaration

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, makefile

I have two libraries in my include path:

```
/usr/local/include/lib1/
/user/include/lib2/
```

Both define a header file "vec.h" and I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/lib1/vec.h:22: error: redeclared with...
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Are they both the same `vec.h`? Otherwise, which one do you ever intend to use?

Comment: No, they are different.. i am not using them, just want to work with both libs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do:

```
#include "lib1/vec.h"
#include "lib2/vec.h"
```

Your makefile should then have include paths up to the lib1 and lib2.

```
-I /usr/local/include /user/include
```

You should ensure that the headers have guards around them to make sure they don't get declared twice.  You should see something like:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H_ab2592zx1__
#define MYHEADER_H_ab2592zx1__

#include ...
#include ...
class ...

#endif
```

You should have these guards regardless of whether you have two includes of the same name and they should typically end with something fairly random in order to limit/lower the possibility that they conflict with a header guard in another file.

Comment: Hmmm, better check that "lib1/vec.h" doesn't declare the same guard symbol as "lib2/vec.h"!

Comment: @Skizz - Good point.  Typically they should end with something fairly random

Comment: thats why you should use `#pragma once` instead of include guards. Supported by both GCC and MSVC.

Comment: #pragma once is a good solution but you should still use include guards as #pragma once is not standard.  Using both together provides the advantages of #pragma once while providing a fallback mechanism when it's not available/supported by the compiler in use.

Comment: I've appended GUIDs to include guard names to prevent this type of collision (I have an editor macro that does this almost automatically). Pretty much no one else likes that; they believe they're ugly and unnecessary.  I agree they're ugly, but as this shows, sometimes they're necessary.

Comment: @Michael - my response to the use of GUIDs and them being ugly would be, yeah - Life's not always pretty!  :)

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, can't comment yet, so posting as an answer.) What exactly is at line 22 of lib1/vec.h and what is the complete error message? It looks like the header is trying to declare something that was already declared in a different way somewhere, which may even have nothing to do with lib2/vec.h.

**EDIT**

So you have a name clash. I don't know what library trimesh2/include/Vec.h belongs to (probably lib2), but the problem is definitely a conflict between this header and lib1/img.h. Two libraries define two different classes with the same name Vec. There is no solution to this problem unless you have sources of one of the libraries and are willing to rename one of Vecs to something else and recompile it. You just can't have two different things with the same name in one program.

Comment: /usr/local/include/lib1/img.h:22: error: redeclared with 1 template parameter(s)
trimesh2/include/Vec.h:82: note: previous declaration ‘template<int D, class T> class Vec’ used 2 template parameter(s)

Comment: In the code: Vec.h: template <int D, class T = float>
class Vec {    and img.h: template <class T>
class Vec
{

Comment: Another solution would be to put them in a namespace.

Comment: Yes, but it can be even more difficult than simply renaming it. Namespaces can be tricky to use especially when portability is considered. I remember some class in a namespace that I couldn't modify in such way that it would compile by both GCC and HP aCC. It had something to do with overloaded operators.